# Por que meu array retorna um undefined

Tags: javascript, array, undefined

Estou com esse código, porem quero acessar um **certo atributo** de um **objeto** que está **dentro de um array**, mas está retornando undefined

```js
obj1 = {
    nome : 'name',
    array : [],
    funcao : function(element){this.array.push(element)},
    getArray : function(){return this.array},
    getNome : function(){this.array.forEach(element =>element.nome) }
}

obj2 = {
    nome: 'name2'
}

obj1.funcao(obj2)
console.log(obj1.getArray())
console.log(obj1.getNome())
```

Comment: Porque falta o `return` ?

Answer (score 1):

Se quer retornar um novo array com a propriedade nome, tente usar o método map, conforme a seguir:

```js
obj1 = {
    nome : 'name',
    array : [],
    funcao : function(element){this.array.push(element)},
    getArray : function(){return this.array;},
    getNome : function(){return this.array.map(element =>element.nome) }
}

obj2 = {
    nome: 'name2'
}

obj1.funcao(obj2)
console.log(obj1.getArray())
console.log(obj1.getNome())
```